# Returning raw soap response in java using JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have have a program where i am invoking the generated code from jax-ws wsimport function.
Here's what it looks like:

```
HolidayService2 service = new HolidayService2();
HolidayService2Soap proxy = service.getHolidayService2Soap();
ArrayOfCountryCode countries = proxy.GetCountriesAvailable("USA");
```

the proxy.GetCountriesAvailable method invokes the webservice and returns an arrayofcountry code. Is there any way i can get the display the raw soap response in my application?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a packet sniffing program or a proxy based program.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great proxy based program or there is the [JAX-WS WSMonitor](http://java.net/projects/wsmonitor/) tool.

For packet sniffing: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

---

To get access to the `SOAPMessage`, you effectively need to create a class that implements the `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler` interface:

```
public class MySoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders ()
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage (final SOAPMessageContext context)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault (final SOAPMessageContext context)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void close (final MessageContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and add this to your service binding's handler chain:

```
final BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) proxy;
final Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding ();
final List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain ();
handlerChain.add (new MySoapHandler ());
binding.setHandlerChain (handlerChain);
```

The magic happens in `handleMessage`/`handleFault` methods of your custom handler. Once you have a `SOAPMessageContext` you call the `getMessage` method and it will return you an instance of `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage`. `SOAPMessage` is an object representation of the raw soap packet. From here you should be able to reconstruct the XML structure for your purposes.

[`SOAPMessage` API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to display the raw data in my application.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party SOAP libraries at runtime?

Comment: No I'm not using any 3rd party libs. Just using the classes that were generated by wsimport.